# How to access Firebase Database on Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to use Firebase in my Android application.

This is my data structure.

[image]

Here I want to retrieve all the posts of logged user if any. I inserted the each blog post as push method.So I need to retrieve the posts which are created by the logged user. I can able to retrieve all the posts inside the Blog key using FirebaseRecyleView. Now i need to retrieve only posts which are created by logged user. I have tried, nothing works for me.

Thanks advance

Comment: I don't understand what you want clearly but those tutorials I am understanding Firebase from they might help you https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLGCjwl1RrtcTXrWuRTa59RyRmQ4OedWrt

Comment: in my application each user can add posts (blog). so when ever a user click on "show my posts" button i need to display the post which are posted by himself such as myposts in facebook

Comment: i already follow that tut.but that is not complete

Comment: have you tried adding `orderByChild("uid").equalTo(user.getUid())` or something like that?

Comment: yes.that doesnt solve the problem

Comment: beacause inorder to get query results i need to go ref.child(Blog).child(key).the problem is that i dont know the key beacause posts are submited using push() method

Comment: you need to access the child of child, I think we are searching for the same thing I am also asking for that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41416490/get-child-of-child

Comment: you don't need that. So it will be like this: `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Blog").orderByChild("uid").equalTo(user.getUid);`. Try that

Comment: @Sreejithsreeji if you've tried something already, show what you've tried.

Comment: Thanks.problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

1.Get the Uid of logged user like this.

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

2.Get your Firebase Database Ref :

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
```

3.Get all the post of logged user from database

```
 List<Blog> myBlogs = new ArrayList();
 database.child("myblog-b2002").child("Blog").orderByChild("uid").equalTo(uid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          if(dataSnapshot==null)return;
          for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
              myBlogs.add(postSnapshot.valueOf(Blog.class));
          }  
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: So `Blog.class` is the child which is one single instance of blog value?

Comment: @psypher yes . I considered a dummy blog.class class name may be different.

Comment: Yes..already got the answer.no i need to convert the query results into firebase recycler view

Comment: Thanks for the replay

Comment: How can i reference uid, if itsn't uid. I mean I have sam database, but, instead of uid, i have index number, 1, 2, so on...

Comment: you can you the index number then , Only thing is it should match the structure of your firebase db.