# Get child of child

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get a child of a child inside each other and add the to a collapsing view in the drawer with the same arrangement, using Firebase and [MaterialDrawer Libarary](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer)

Here is the code of the method by which doing that runs in the onCreate()

```
private void addDrawerItems() {
    RootRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            result.addItem(IntentItemDrawer = new ExpandableDrawerItem()
                    .withName(String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getKey()))
                    .withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_collection_case_play)
                    .withIdentifier(t++).withSelectable(false).withSubItems(
                            new SecondaryDrawerItem()
                                    .withName(String.valueOf(RootRef.child(dataSnapshot.getKey()).child(dataSnapshot.getKey())))
                                    .withLevel(2)
                                    .withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_8tracks)
                                    .withIdentifier(t++)));
```

The wrong is in the line `.withName(String.valueOf(RootRef.child(dataSnapshot.getKey()).child(dataSnapshot.getKey())))` That I want to display the child of child name in it

**Edit :**

Here is my database structure

[image]

and what I am trying to do is to have their keys/names in the same structure in the drawer

Like this but instead of the links appearing I want to display

[image]

test1,test2,damn,ddddd... and so on

---

### Edit 2 :

I have tried to decompose the method but with `NullPointerException` I think I can works but need some modifications

1. **In the `addDrawerItems()`**

   ```
   {....
   .withIdentifier(t++).withSelectable(false).withSubItems(testMethod(dataSnapshot)));}
   ```
2. **testMethod(dataSnapshot)**

   ```
   private List<IDrawerItem> testMethod(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       RootRef.child(dataSnapshot.getKey()).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
           @Override
           public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
               createSub(dataSnapshot);
           }
   ....
       });
       return null;
   }
   ```
3. **createSub(dataSnapshot)**

   ```
   private void createSub(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       new SecondaryDrawerItem()
               .withName(String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getKey()))
               .withLevel(2)
               .withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_8tracks)
               .withIdentifier(t++);
   }
   ```

Comment: It will be a lot easier if you attach sample of your database and mention which node you want to take

Comment: @koceeng will you please explain more or to add an explained code to answers so I can accept it

Comment: I can't answer your question yet without knowing for sure what your database looks like and which data you want to get

Comment: @koceeng I have edit the post to explain to you

Comment: I did not exactly get your question, would getting the child key/value you want help?

Comment: @AseedUsmani I want the key but for a child of a child for exaple in subItem (thats name appeas as alink in th drawer ) i wast to desplay "test1"

Comment: I haven't played with navigation drawer much, if you want I can help you with getting keys and values of your Firebase JSON tree.

Comment: sure, and it is not related to drawer as so, the drawer limit is only that when add for example "Intent" then must add "test1", "test2" after adding "Intent" directly, thats all,  Also it will beh much easier if could to replace the single line of code that i mentioned with a one which get the child of the child name

Comment: have you tried adding .getKey() at the end of the line you mentioned caused the error? Otherwise you refer to a Reference which calls toString and gives the url.  and then String.valueOf would be redundant: `.withName(RootRef.child(dataSnapshot.getKey()).child(dataSnapshot.getKey()).getKey())`

Comment: .getKey and the wohle line doesn't make sense as what is being translated to the fire base is child of the same named child then geting the 1st parent name that's the same name already, child("Intent").child("Intent") then get the name which is Intent, i am just removed the getKey() in order to ready the refrence for my self in Logs to trace the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the concept is like this:

```
RootRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        // since this event called from root,
        // then dataSnapshot key will contain "Intent", "else", "sdsd"
        // and dataSnapshot value is their child node

        // knowing that, you should create your parent Drawer Item here,

        // and next, you want to add sub item to that parent Drawer item,
        // with your child data from that parent,
        // like "test1" and "test2" for "Intent" parent

        // you should achieve it like this
        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            // in here, childSnapshot.getKey() should return "test1",
            // then "test2", depending on the loop count.
            // and childSnapshot.getValue() should return "2"

        }
    }
}
```

I don't have enough knowledge yet to answer you with practical implementation on MaterialDrawer Library, but I hope you can fill the rest.

**EDIT:**

I think I might try to help without knowing that library. Correct me if I'm wrong. Try this:

```
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    ExpandableDrawerItem parentItem = new ExpandableDrawerItem()
                .withName(String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getKey()))
                .withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_collection_case_play)
                .withIdentifier(t++).withSelectable(false);

    for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        parentItem.withSubItems(new SecondaryDrawerItem()
            .withName(String.valueOf(childSnapshot.getKey()))
            .withLevel(2)
            .withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_8tracks)
            .withIdentifier(t++));
    }

    result.addItem(parentItem);
}
```

Note: if `withSubItems` only take one value then replace it. I think it won't work. But since in comment you mention that it can, I think you know the way to do that.

**EDIT 2:**

This is inside `onChildChange()` method:

```
final HashMap<String, ExpandableDrawerItem> parentItemMap = new HashMap<>();

RootRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        // code from my first edit here

        parentItemMap.put(dataSnapshot.getKey(), parentItem);
    }

    public void onChildChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        ExpandableDrawerItem parentItem = parentItemMap.get(dataSnapshot.getKey());

        parentItem.withName( ... ) .... ; // like inside onChildCreate()

        // also do the dataSnapshot.getChildren loop here

        // but DONT add the result.addItem();
    }
```

Comment: enhanced for loop won't help because it will make the drawerItem and drawerSubItem names in buggy way niether Items or SubItems have the same length

Comment: I think you miss the point. Let me ask you this first to make me a little bit understanding `MaterialDrawer Library`, in your code, there are `addItem` and `withSubItems`. Can that two be separated? I mean can you create the parent item first (with `addItem`) and then attach sub items on it later?

Comment: as I tried the drawer and the onAddChild I think it's no, the onAddChild if it adds the Items then the SubItems it will add all of the subItems in the last Item, also when I add Childs while running the app the child go to its place correctly

Comment: @DasserBasyouni then can 1 parent item contains more than 1 subItem?

Comment: yes also I want to inside of them later for more and more data, see my edit please

Comment: @DasserBasyouni, check my edited answer. And by looking at your second edit, I think you need to study more about Java and Android. The way it works and the flow.

Comment: I'm sorry but that's not getting the child of child when it updates

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132059/discussion-between-koceeng-and-dasser-basyouni).